# Images rotated when added to PDF in itext7

Tags: pdf, rotation, itext, itext7

I'm using the following extension method I built on top of itext7's `com.itextpdf.layout.Document` type to apply images to PDF documents in my application:

```kotlin
fun Document.writeImage(imageStream: InputStream, page: Int, x: Float, y: Float, width: Float, height: Float) {

    val imageData = ImageDataFactory.create(imageStream.readBytes())
    val image = Image(imageData)
    val pageHeight = pdfDocument.getPage(page).pageSize.height

    image.scaleAbsolute(width, height)

    val lowerLeftX = x
    val lowerLeftY = pageHeight - y - image.imageScaledHeight

    image.setFixedPosition(page, lowerLeftX, lowerLeftY)

    add(image)
}
```

Overall, this works -- but with one exception! I've encountered a subset of documents where the images are placed as if the document origin is rotated 90 degrees.  Even though the content of the document is presented properly oriented underneath.

[Here is a redacted copy of one of the PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p459sX2HqnAbUmroT5ZTQcX5avgBDlAs/view?usp=sharing)s I'm experiencing this issue with. I'm wondering if anyone would be able to tell me why itext7 is having difficulties writing to this document, and what I can do to fix it -- or alternatively, if it's a potential bug in the higher level functionality of `com.itextpdf.layout` in itext7?

---

#### Some Additional Notes

- I'm aware that drawing on a PDF works via a series of instructions concatenated to the PDF. The code above works on other PDFs we've had issues with in the past, so `com.itextpdf.layout.Document` does appear to be normalizing the coordinate space prior to drawing. Thus, the issue I describe above seems to be going undetected by itext?
- The rotation metadata in the PDF that itext7 reports from a "good" PDF without this issue seems to be the same as the rotation metadata in PDFs like the one I've linked above. This means I can't perform some kind of brute-force fix through detection.
- I would love any solution to not require me to flatten the PDF through any form of broad operation.

Comment: In the document, all the pages but the first one have the 270-degree rotation

Answer (score 1):

I can talk only about the document you`ve shared.

It contains 4 pages.

/Rotate property of the first page is 0, for other pages is 270 (defines 90 rotation counterclockwise).

[image: e.g page 3]

**IText indeed tries to normalize the coordinate space for each page.**

That`s why when you add an image to pages 2-4 of the document it is rotated on 270 (90 counterclockwise) degrees.

> ... Even though the content of the document is presented properly oriented underneath.

Content of pages 2-4 looks like

```
q
0 -612 792 0 0 612 cm
/Im0 Do
Q
```

This is an image with applied transformation.
`0 -612 792 0 0 612 cm`  represents the composite transformation matrix.
From ISO 32000

> A transformation matrix in PDF shall be specified by six numbers,
> usually in the form of an array containing six elements. In its most
> general form, this array is denoted [a b c d e f]; it can represent
> any linear transformation from one coordinate system to another.

We can extract a rotation from that matrix.

*How to decompose the matrix you can find there.*
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237369/given-this-transformation-matrix-how-do-i-decompose-it-into-translation-rotati

The rotation is defined by the next matrix

```
 0  -1 
 1   0
```

This is a rotation on  -90 (270) degrees.

**Important note:**  in this case positive angle means counterclockwise rotation.

ISO 32000

> Rotations shall be produced by [rc rs -rs rc 0 0], where rc = cos(q)
> and rs = sin(q) which has the effect of rotating the coordinate system
> axes by an angle q **counter clockwise**.

So the image has been rotated on the same angle in the counter direction comparing to the page.